# Ansible task includes undefined var, despite being defined in defaults/main.yml

Tags: variables, ansible, yaml, undefined, default

I am trying to create a Galaxy role for our org's internal galaxy, which I am testing first locally. In our org we use a common list of defaults across all roles.

Ansible is throwing me a *"The task includes an option with an undefined variable The error was: 'redis_download_url' is undefined"* error when running my playbook, despite me having defined the variable in *defaults/main.yml*:

```
# Download
redis_version: "6.2.3"
redis_download_url: "https://download.redis.io/releases/redis-{{ redis_version }}.tar.gz"
```

When running my simple *role/playbook.yml*

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/main.yml
```

Linked to *tasks/main.yml*

```
---
- name: Check ansible version
  assert:
    that: "ansible_version.full is version_compare('2.4', '>=')"
    msg: "Please use Ansible 2.4 or later"

- include: download.yml
  tags:
    - download

- include: install.yml
  tags:
    - install
```

It should pull the tar file from *tasks/download.yml* as stated:

```
---
- name: Download Redis
  get_url:
    url: "{{ redis_download_url }}"
    dest: /usr/local/src/redis-{{ redis_version }}.tar.gz

- name: Extract Redis tarball
  unarchive:
    src: /usr/local/src/redis-{{ redis_version }}.tar.gz
    dest: /usr/local/src
    creates: /usr/local/src/redis-{{ redis_version }}/Makefile
    copy: no
```

The *redis_download_url* var is defined in *defaults/main.yml* which as I understand ansible should be able to locate there. I also have similar vars defined in *defaults/task.yml* eg.

```
redis_user: redis
redis_group: "{{ redis_user }}"
redis_port: "6379"
redis_root_dir: "/opt/redis"
redis_config_dir: "/etc/redis"
redis_conf_file: "{{ redis_config_dir }}/{{ redis_port }}.conf"
redis_password: "change-me"
redis_protected_mode: "yes"
```

and I assume they are also not able to be found/seen by ansible (but it does not get that far). I have also checked all file permissions and they seem to be fine.

Apologies in advance if the question is badly formatted.

Comment: If you wanted to use roles in playbook, why not use `include_role` or `roles: ["rolename"]`?

Comment: You are including a task file from a path which happens to be located in a role but ansible does not really care about this latest  assertion. If you want to execute the role, either add it to the `roles` section in your play or use `(include|import)_role`. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#search-paths-in-ansible):

> If you include a task file from a role, it will NOT trigger role behavior, this only happens when running as a role, include_role will work.

To get the role functionality of reading variables from `defaults/main.yml`, you'll need to use `include_role` or `roles: []`.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: myrole
```

OR

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: true

  roles:
    - myrole
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the first example doesn't seem to be valid yaml however but it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helped. That's strange. Running a `--syntax-check` with the first example checks out ok.